# Проверка на предыдущее значение таблицы

Tags: java, сравнение

Например, у меня имеется столбец с Именами:

```
Олег 
Олег
Олег
Петя
Петя
```

Как мне правильно сравнить что Петя != Олегу, т.е как сравнить Текущее значение с предыдущим?

Comment: В Java нет такого стандартного понятия как "столбец"

Comment: `if (Петя != Олегу) {...} else {...}` что сложного то?

Comment: Петя и Олег просто примеры. у меня есть одна переменная  из этой таблцы: name. и когда я делаю getString я получаю либо Петю либо Олега, вот как быть в этом случае?

Comment: Столбец это поле в БД или что?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Снова [вопрос группировки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/648829/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B), но уже алгоритмического характера? :) Есть два способа. Предположим, что "поля строки" у вас хранятся в классе типа Item:

```
class Item {
    private String name;
    private int hours;
    private int income;

    public Item(String name, int hours, int income) {
        this.name = name;
        this.hours = hours;
        this.income = income;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public int getHours() {
        return this.hours;
    }

    public int getIncome() {
        return this.income;
    }

    // Сеттеры опущены для краткости
}
```

Первый способ простой - перебором:

```
List<Item> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new Item("Вася", 8, 100));
list.add(new Item("Вася", 8, 90));
list.add(new Item("Вася", 8, 120));
list.add(new Item("Ваня", 12, 150));
list.add(new Item("Петя", 6, 70));
list.add(new Item("Петя", 10, 100));

System.out.printf("%s %20s %15s\n", "Имя", "Рабочие часы", "Инкассировано");
System.out.println("------------------------------------------");

String lastName = list.get(0).getName();
int hours = 0;
int income = 0;
for (Item item : list) {
    if (item.getName() != lastName) {
        lastName = item.getName();
        hours = 0;
        income = 0;
        System.out.printf("Итого: %18d %15d\n", hours, income);
    }
    hours += item.getHours();
    income += item.getIncome();
    System.out.printf("%s %20d %15d\n", item.getName(), item.getHours(), item.getIncome());
}
```

Второй сложнее - группировка:

```
System.out.printf("%s %20s %15s\n", "Имя", "Рабочие часы", "Инкассировано");
System.out.println("------------------------------------------");
Map<String, List<Item>> groups = list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Item::getName));
for (Map.Entry<String, List<Item>> entry : groups.entrySet()) {
    int hours = 0;
    int income = 0;
    for (Item item : entry.getValue()) {
        hours += item.getHours();
        income += item.getIncome();
        System.out.printf("%s %20d %15d\n", item.getName(), item.getHours(), item.getIncome());
    }
    System.out.printf("Итого: %18d %15d\n", hours, income);
}
```

Но он более гибкий. В частности, ему не важен порядок элементов в исходном списке.

Comment: Ага. До перебора тоже додумался, а вот второй способ интересный.

Comment: Можно вопрос в догонку?
Я реализовал с помощью перебора:
<!-- language: lang-java -->  
if (!prevsmallcard.equals(smallcard))
                      {
                       sls = rec1.getLong("ls");
                       sfactsum = rec1.getLong("factsum");
                       small_factsum += sfactsum;
                       counter++;
                       dtSMALL.addRecord("Итого", "---", sls, null, null, null, null);
                       prevsmallcard = smallcard;
                      }
добавляется запись так:О - Олег, п петя
Олег
Итого
О
О
П
И
П
П
О
И
О

Comment: Видимо, есть какие-то нюансы используемой вами платформы, которые вы не учитываете.